# On Insert data in ms sql db using android it shows exception as "data truncation"

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

this is my android coding I get exception on android mobile as "data truncation" how can I solve this, I am using Android studio 3.0.1 and Microsoft sql server and I used jtds1.3.1.jar as jdbc driver library

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String item = params[0];//username.getText().toString();
            String batch =params[1]; //password.getText().toString();
            String mtrs = params[2];
            String design = params[3];

            ConnectDb db = new ConnectDb();

                try
                {
                    con = db.connectionclass();  // Connect to database
                    if (con == null)
                    {
                        z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Change below query according to your own database.

                        String query = /*"select barcode from ce where id=4445";*/"INSERT INTO [CE]([Barcode],[Rack],[Selves],[ItemCode],[BatchNo],[Design],[Qty])VALUES('Null','Null','Null','"+item+"','"+batch+"','"+design+"','"+mtrs+"');";
                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                       if(rs.next())
                       {
                           z="Updated";
                            isSuccess=true;
                            con.close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           z = "Invalid Credentials!";
                            isSuccess = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = ex.getMessage();
                }

            return z;
        }}
```

please help me to solve the problem

Comment: This sounds like perhaps one of the strings you are inserting is too wide for the column.  Please _edit_ your question and show us a) the data being inserted and b) the table definition.

Comment: "INSERT INTO [CE]([Barcode],[Rack],[Selves],[ItemCode],[BatchNo],[Design],[Qty])VALUES('Null','Null','Null','"+item+"','"+batch+"','"+design+"','"+mtrs+"');

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no. to quote the api: "An exception thrown as a DataTruncation exception (on writes) or reported as a DataTruncation warning (on reads) when a data values is unexpectedly truncated for reasons other than its having execeeded MaxFieldSize." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DataTruncation.html

Comment: item=BMC046  batch=VA00019/412/F140/013/1 design=F140  mtrs=8

Comment: @Stultuske Are you sure this is a Java message?  If so, then what could be the cause?

Comment: ID int 
Barcode nvarchar(1000) 
Rack nvarchar(1000) 
Selves nvarchar(1000) 
ItemCode nvarchar(600) 
BatchNo nvarchar(1000) 
Design nvarchar(500) 
Qty nvarchar(1000) 
  this is length of field in my table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no idea. I first thought the same as you, but then I remembered that gem from the api. Am I 100% sure? well, no. but You would have to be a real screwed up developer writing an error message that portrays your Exception as something it isn't (either that, or a developer that really likes to see colleagues debugging)

Comment: I didn't get correct result from this

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no. to quote the api: "An exception thrown as a DataTruncation exception (on writes) or reported as a DataTruncation warning (on reads) when a data values is unexpectedly truncated for reasons other than its having execeeded MaxFieldSize." docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DataTruncation.ht‌​ml – Stultuske